# Checkbox staying unchecked/checked on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to see if a checkbox is true or false and then alert something if it's one or the other, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Eventually I want to set a cookie if the checkbox is true. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Right now it constantly alerts hello.

```
$('#night-mode').on('click', function(){

    $('#team-select').css('background', '#313131');
    $('.color').css('background', '#313131');
    $('html .game-cards, body .game-cards').css('background', '#737373');
    $('html .menu li a, body .menu li a').css('color', '#9ecd1a');
    $('html .menu select, body .menu select').css('background', '#9ecd1a');
    if ($('input.night-mode').prop('checked', false)){
        alert('hello')
    } else if($('input.night-mode').prop('checked', true)){
        alert('not-checked')
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `if` is **setting** the state of `checked` to `false`: `if ($('input.night-mode').prop('checked', false)){`

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: Your life would be so much easier if you just toggled a class on the body.

Comment: @Bkes I think you need to read that again.

Comment: @epascarello hah, probably true

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the checked property with: `.prop(propName, newValue)`. You only need to access the value of it.

```js
$('#night-mode').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')){
        alert('hello')
    } else {
        alert('not-checked')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Night Mode? <input type="checkbox" id="night-mode" value="nm">
```